Managing AOSP Devices with Device Admin API
can AOSP devices be managed by the device admin API?
Hi,
I have been researching on the android device management for quite some time and I eventually got to know that the 'ANDROID MANAGEMENT API' is the thing which manages the android device along with the android device policy. But all of a sudden I thought if andriod devices are managed by the android management API then how can AOSP devices be managed. So i dug it a little deep and got to know about the 'DEVICE ADMIN API(legacy)' is a API that is built in into the android itself for management purposes and it is available from the android 2.
After that i came across this article from AOSP which says that device admin api is a android enterprise feature. Now I got this question if the device admin API is a android enterprise used api then how will it work on the AOSP? as android enterprise requires GMS.
And I am struck on this a week and i could not figure it out. I wish someone could help.
Thanks !
